# What are the benefits of a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, web-services, http, xmlhttprequest

What are the benefits of a XML HTTP request? A given server could send data (e.g. some JSON serialization) for a normal request (non-XHR) as it would send data for a XHR request. And that data could be processed asynchronously (by a browser for example) as well. So why was the XMLHttpRequest invented?

Some things I can think of:

- To use the same URL for HTML and a web service
- To let the server know that this must be processed fast.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest exist before JSON back to year 1999(i guess,since is support for exchange 2000), answer your questions?

Comment: JSON was an example. Then let's say XML. Also XHR is still used, and I hope not for only some ancient convention.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, one of the first uses of XmlHttpRequest was for OWA, which used WebDAV on the wire. So show me how to do methods other than GET/POST without it.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing about XHR is that it's asynchronous and you can have several concurrently running XHR requests. For example you can have several informers on your web page, all updating independently and concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest (or ActiveXObject in IE) is what allows Javascript to make HTTP requests.  It was created to be able to retrieve data in Javascript without having to change the page/refresh the browser.

There are non-javascript ways of retrieving data without refreshing the page, but if you are using Javascript XMLHttpRequest is the way to go.  Many libraries have simplified the use of this call by implementing ajax functions in their libraries (jQuery.ajax() for example) which causes most people to not even realize that XMLHttpRequest is the underlying call behind it.

Comment: Why does Javascript then not just do a normal request in the background, like requesting a other site ... then processing the results (also in the background) and do whatever it wants. I am aware of the Javascript XMLHttpRequest object, but why does it use special headers for the request? What special feature (that couldn't be done without that header) do I expect from the server by using that kind of request?

Comment: There's no special feature from the server.  All it's doing is grabbing a web page from the server like any other http request.  The server doesn't have to do anything differently because it's an xhr call unless you want it to so you can make things on the client easier.

Comment: So `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in the request header is just a bit of extra information that is not really needed, but may lead the server to some extra feature if it wants to? Is that right?

Answer (score -1):

I think the biggest reason it exists is that it predates an Ajax JSON request. It was originally the only way to do AJAX based things. It's still useful when requesting an HTML page and populating an HTML element with the information requested. It's much simpler to use XHR in that instance instead of parsing the JSON and reading out a variable.

I guess the simple answer is that if you're looking for a single piece of data it would be a simpler request to process.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see where the response is that much different. The server can send back exactly the same data with or without XHR. Couldn't a normal request not just send back a single piece of data?